# Is there a cocoa sample code to demonstrate how to access global instance/variable via delegate?

Tags: cocoa

I prefer to access the global instance/variable via delegate.
( I do not like the mode as

```
extern  NSInteger  myInstance
```

)
This means that all global instances/variables are in a delegate object.
In cocoa touch, I know I can use

```
appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
appDelegate.myInstance=1;
```

to access the global instance(myInstance), but I am not sure if it is same as the mode in Cocoa.
Is there a cocoa sample code to demonstrate how to access global instance/variable via delegate?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cocoa it's `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` and `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`.

You can also use the global `NSApp` as shorthand; see the [NSApplication Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks.but appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];